# cuda __syncthreads() not working in my code

Tags: c++, cuda

So here's the situation.

I have a block of threads running a while loop and I need the loop to continue if and only if some condition is met by any of these threads. To do that I use a shared variable as the continue flag, the flag is cleared by thread #0 at the beginning of each iteration, followed by a `__syncthreads()`, and can be set by any thread during the iteration if the continue condition is met. Then another call to `__syncthreads()` is placed before the checking point of next iteration to make sure threads are synchronized. The kernel is basically like this:

```
__global__ void foo(void* data) {
    __shared__ int blockContinueFlag;
    do {
        if (threadIdx.x || threadIdx.y || threadIdx.z) {
            blockContinueFlag = 0;
        }
        __syncthreads(); //synch1
        //some data manipulations...
        if(some predicate) {
            blockContinueFlag = true;
        }
        //some data manipulations...
        __syncthreads(); //synch2
    } while (blockContinueFlag);
}
```

The problem is the barrier synch2 doesn't seem to work in my code, sometimes the kernel terminates even when the continue condition is met by some threads (I know this by checking returned data on host side). To further exam this I set a break point just after the do-while loop like following code , where sometimes the `blockContinueFlag` is said `true` (I can only assume the block exited the loop prior to some threads can set `blockContinueFlag`).

```
__global__ void foo(void* data) {
    __shared__ int blockContinueFlag;
    do {
        if (threadIdx.x || threadIdx.y || threadIdx.z) {
            blockContinueFlag = 0;
        }
        __syncthreads(); //synch1
        //some data manipulations...
        if(some predicate) {
            blockContinueFlag = true;
        }
        //some data manipulations...
        __syncthreads(); //synch2
    } while (blockContinueFlag);
    //a break point is set here
}
```

I remember reading from cuda manual that `__syncthreads()` is allowed in conditional clause if the predicate is evaluated same for all threads, which should be in this case.

I have another simplified version of code just as an illustration for this.

```
__global__ void foo(int* data, int kernelSize, int threshold) {
    __shared__ int blockContinueFlag;
    do {
        if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
            blockContinueFlag = 0;
        }
        __syncthreads();
        if (threadIdx.x < kernelSize)  {
            data[threadIdx.x]--;
            for (int i = 0; i < threadIdx.x; i++);
            if (data[threadIdx.x] > threshold)
                blockContinueFlag = true;
        }
        __syncthreads();
    } while (blockContinueFlag);
}

int main()
{
    int hostData[1024], *deviceData;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        hostData[i] = i;
    cudaMalloc(&deviceData, 1024 * sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(deviceData, hostData, 1024 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    foo << <1, 1024 >> >(deviceData, 512, 0);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(hostData, deviceData, 1024 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    fprintf(stderr, cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
    return 0;

}
```

The expected value for `hostData[]` would be `{-511, -510, -509, ..., 0, 512, 513, 514,..., 1023}` at the end of `main()`, which is sometimes the actual case. But in some case it produces following values in VS 2013 debug mode

```
[0]: -95
[1]: -94
...
[29]: -66
[30]: -65
[31]: -64
[32]: 31
[33]: 32
[34]: 33
...
[61]: 60
[62]: 61
[63]: 62
[64]: -31
[65]: -30
[66]: -29
...
[92]: -3
[93]: -2
[94]: -1
[95]: 0
[96]: 95
[97]: 96
[98]: 97
...
```

, which suggests warps are not actually synchronized.

So does anyone know the reason for this and/or whether there is a way to let the thread barrier work correctly?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be related with some compiler optimization or with the *// some data manipulation* code you have ommited. Try to declare the flag of the loop as `volatile __shared__ int  blockContinueFlag`

Comment: I'm with @pQB. This is likely to be caused by compiler optimisation. What architecture, build flags and CUDA version are you using for this?

Comment: Thanks guys but i've figured it out already. Another __syncthreads() should be added at the start of each iteration before thread#0 clears blockContinueFlag, to ensure thread#0 doesn't race to next iteration and clear the flag before other threads check it.

Comment: Actually, I think you have forced the compiler to 'notice' that the variable must be read/write by all the threads with that extra synchronization. If you try to declare the variable as volatile and come with the results, as well as the details @talonmies asked, then someone could make a quality answer. In addition, you may be introducing more synchronization barriers that the really needed in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example you have checking the condition and clearing the flag in the same code fragment between syncthreads. That's a write-after-read hazard.
To better exemplifiy your problem, let me rewrite your example like this:

```
__global__ void foo(void* data) {
  __shared__ int blockContinueFlag;
  blockContinueFlag = true;
  while (true) {
    if (!blockContinueFlag)
        break;
    if (threadIdx.x || threadIdx.y || threadIdx.z) {
        blockContinueFlag = 0;
    }
    __syncthreads(); //synch1
    //some data manipulations...
    if(some predicate) {
      blockContinueFlag = true;
    }
    //some data manipulations...
    __syncthreads(); //synch2
  };
```

In this example, the check for the flag and the loop break is more verbose, but it is essentially the same code (plus the redundant check at the very beginning).

In this example, as well as in your code, the thread 0 may check the loop condition *and* clear the flag, before thread 33 (another warp) performs the check. This causes divergence, and all the evil gets loose.

To fix - you need to add yet another `__syncthreads()` before clearing the flag.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out. I also realized it some time after I post this question. Now I am using one __syncthreads_or() instead of three __syncthreads()s.

Comment: Pleas post the code for your solution with `__syncthreads_or()`. It seems like this might be valuable to others as well.

Comment: I do not see the same write-after-read hazard in the first code of the question. You have changed the _do ... while_ for a _while_ loop and so the line where the condition is checked (the assembly code should be the same). In the question code, all the threads are synchronized _after_ the `blockContinueFlag` is initialized, and _before_ checking the predicate, and then, threads are synchronized again _after_  updating the flag and before the next loop iteration. So, I still think that there is an aggresive compiler optimization that could be fixed declaring the shared variable as `volatile`.

Comment: After the last __syncthreads() all threads do: check the loop condition, zero the blockConfigureFlag. That's the write-after-read. All I did is to make the checking for the loop conition more explicit. You need to synchronize after checking the condition and *clearing* the flag.

Answer (score 3):

So here's my solution with one `__syncthreads_or()` instead of three `__syncthreads()` as requested.

```
__global__ void foo(void* data) {
    int blockContinueFlag;
    do {
        blockContinueFlag = 0;
        //some data manipulations...
        if(some predicate) {
            blockContinueFlag = true;
        }
        //some data manipulations...
    } while (__syncthreads_or(blockContinueFlag));
}
```

In practice this is slightly faster than three syncthreads's.

Thanks again for your posts.

Comment: Note, it consumes 1 extra register throughout the computation.